# LINQ query from two related lists with specific criteria

Tags: c#, linq

Using SQL Server and C#:
I have 3 tables: Employee (**EmployeeId, JobDescription**), CashAllowance (**CashAllowanceId**) and EmployeeCashAllowance (**EmployeeId, CashAllowanceId, ValueTaken, DateAdded**).
Employee has (EmployeeeId) as primary key, CashAllowance has (CashAllowanceId) as primary key, EmployeeCashAllowance has 2 foreign keys (EmployeeId and CashAllowanceId) related to the first 2 tables.

I need to get the list of (**EmployeeCashAllowance**) in a specific date + for specific **CashAllowanceId** + for employees having **JobDescription = "Dev"**

I need to achieve this in a LINQ query on lists filled from DB where list of all EmployeeCashAllowance is a property of the Employee object (each Employee object has List ListEmployeeCashAllowances as a property). What I wrote was this:

```
var sumValues = (from e in Employees
                        where (e.JobDescription == "Dev")
                        from c in e.ListEmployeeCashAllowances
                        where (c.EmployeeId == e.EmployeeId && c.CashAllowanceId == selectedCashAllowanceId && c.DateAdded == selectedDate)
                        select c).ToList();
```

But this is not working as I expected, it's returning all rows in Employee and EmployeeCashAllowance whatever the selected criteria is (even is JobDescription is not Dev and CashAllowanceId is not the selectedCashAllowanceId).

Where did I go wrong with this?

Comment: The 'select s' seems to be a clue that your code was trimmed to be posted  here, right? Linq does work like you spected (I wouldn't use 2 'where').

Comment: @Caverna yes you're right, I changed it here while writing from s to c. I corrected it now. But it's not giving me the desired results, it's selecting all the items in the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't expect this, but I had to change from the query to get what I want, with the restriction that I had use "Sum" and get sum of values in the list of EmployeeCashAllowance resulted:

```
Employees.SelectMany(e => e.ListEmployeeCashAllowances).Where(lc => lc.CashAllowanceId == selectedCashAllowanceId).Select(c => c.ValueTaken).Sum();
```

Note that if I don't use Sum the list returned will contain all items in all the ListEmployeeCashAllowances.

Answer (score 0):

You better use join I suppose try something like this , I haven't tested so it must look like this

```
var sumValues = (from e in Employees
                    join c in EmployeeCashAllowances on e.EmployeeId equals c.EmployeeId 
                    where ( c.CashAllowanceId == selectedCashAllowanceId && c.DateAdded == selectedDate && e.JobDescription == "Dev")
                    select c).ToList();
```

Comment: Can't use join like this because EmployeeCashAllowances here in a property of each Employee "e".

Answer (score 0):

Not Tested, Just gave a try

```
var results = from e in Employees
              from ec in e.EmployeeCashAllowances
              where (e.EmployeeId == ec.EmployeeId && ec.CashAllowanceId == selectedCashAllowanceId && ec.DateAdded == selectedDate && e.JobDescription == "Dev")
              select ec;
```

Comment: Can't use join like this because EmployeeCashAllowances here in a property of each Employee "e".

Comment: @Saleem - Just gave a try as I couldn't get your class mapping correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes clear when you clean the formatting:

```
var sumValues =
    from e in Employees
    where
        e.JobDescription == "Dev"
    from c in e.ListEmployeeCashAllowances // Gotcha!!!
    where
        c.EmployeeId == e.EmployeeId &&    // Is that really necessary?
        c.CashAllowanceId == selectedCashAllowanceId &&
        c.DateAdded == selectedDate
    select c;
```

Normally I use LINQ methods like:

```
var query = Employees
    .Where(e => e.JobDescription == "Dev")
    .SelectMany(e => e.ListEmployeeCashAllowances)
    .Where(c =>
        c.CashAllowanceId == selectedCashAllowanceId &&
        c.DateAdded == selectedDate);
```

But 'e.ListEmployeeCashAllowances' still can be selecting all users...
A long shot, without knowing your environment, could be:

```
var query = Employees
    .SelectMany(e => e.ListEmployeeCashAllowances)
    .Where(c =>
        c.JobDescription == "Dev" &&
        c.CashAllowanceId == selectedCashAllowanceId &&
        c.DateAdded == selectedDate);
```

Resolving what to do with 'query', you can simply do:

```
var sumValues = query.Sum(c => c.ValueTaken);
```